# In Extjs4 how can I reconfigure an existing menu object?

Tags: json, extjs, menu, extjs4

In extjs4 how can I set the menus in a call later (from), not in the initComponent function?

In other words: How can I reconfigure an existing menu object (menu items)?

```
Ext.define('My.view.dashboard.CategoryMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',
alias: 'widget.categorymenu',
id: 'kategoriaMenu',

initComponent: function() {                
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

fetchMenu: function(categoryId) {
    var me=this;

    Ext.Ajax.request(
               {
                url: '/resources/categoryMenu.json',
                method: 'POST',
                params:
                {
                 id: categoryId
                },
                success: function(result, request)
                {
                 var jsonData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
                 categoryItems=jsonData.items;
                 Ext.apply(me.items, categoryItems);                     
                }
               });
    }

});
```

This is the original code what is a working code with initComponent initialization:

```
initComponent: function() {             

                Ext.apply(this, {
        items:
        [
            {
                text: 'Recently Added (last 7 Days)',
                itemId: 'recentlyAdded'
            },
             {
                text: 'Open  Worklist',
                iconCls: 'worklist-icon',
                itemId: 'openWorklist'
            },{
                text: 'Open Create Screen',
                iconCls: 'open-create-screen-icon',
                itemId: 'openCreateScreen'
            }
        ]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
},
```

This is how I call it:

```
        ...
        var ctxMenu = this.getCategoryMenu();
        ctxMenu.fetchMenu(record.data.id);  // get current menu content         
        ctxMenu.setPosition(event.getXY());
        ctxMenu.show();
        ...
```

Comment: i think you are adding them correctly but you need to force the component layout to be recalculated ... so call ctxMenu.doLayout() before you show the component ...

Comment: I tried to call ctxMenu.doLayout(), but nothing. Otherwise me.add is working. But this is not enough in its own, because, then every time I click the menus added over the menus already exist in the object. So there is 2 solution:
- I destroy the object, and newly create it
- I reconfigure, only the menu items somehow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Ext4, but it should be the same concept as 3. For my app, I had to set the menu items dynamically based on a grid item that they were right clicking on (this was for a ContextMenu, but it *should* be the same)

```
ctxMenu.items.items[0]
// items.items because you're nested inside a menu
```

Will retrieve the first menu item, and from there you can get the others easily (1, 2, 3). Once you have that you can use `setText()`. You should have access to all of the `Ext.menu.Item` methods from there.

Comment: I don't want to get the menus out. I want to replace all the menu structure. var ctxMenu = this.getCategoryMenu(); called as many times as I clicked on a list element.